# Prevent Windows SmartScreen from blocking application in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, certificate, publishing, microsoft-smartscreen

I wrote a program for my personal use in Visual Studio 2013 and am trying to get it to run without Windows SmartScreen popping up every time I run the executable.

I've been searching for about two hours now and have tried a number of different methods, including unblocking the file in PowerShell, editing permissions for the extension in Group Policy Editor, changing registry entries and several others.

I'm starting to wonder if the only possible way to do this is to purchase a certificate, which I don't really want to do for a simple, personal project like this. It's not like I'll be distributing the thing.

There's got to be some work-around to this...

Comment: SmartScreen should only be popping up if you download a program ...

Comment: Create a self-signed certificate then signed the executable.

Comment: @Ramhound - After Googling how to do that my hopes went up until I realized I don't have access to IIS - I'm on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: @marky this may help: http://woshub.com/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/

Comment: @Lister - After a quick scan, that may be my solution. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @marky No worries, I cant vouch for it, whenever I've needed to do it at work I just used the certificate authority was much easier :P

Comment: @marky What does not having IIS have to creating your own certificate to sign your application?

Comment: @Ramhound - Because the instructions that I found at several sources on creating a certificate required doing something in IIS. If you know of another way, please let me know (I haven't yet tried the instructions at the link that Lister posted).